# How to define a function like 1/f(x)

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to define a function `f(x)` such that `1/f(x) = 1/R - A/B`. I know that I can just work the RHS out so that `f(x) = C/D` and then define it like that, but I was wondering if there was a way to directly define the function without simplification. In some cases it may be very difficult to simplify it to get a `f(x) =` form.

Comment: Your code-formatted bits are not Mathematica code -- just to confirm, you want to do this is in the software Mathematica?

Comment: `f[x_]:=1/(1/R - A/B)` ?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes its in Mathematica

Comment: @murray yes like I mentioned, this might not be simple to do in other situations so I wanted a way to define it directly

Comment: Are you looking for a function inverse or a reciprocal?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm looking for a way to define a function f[x] in the form of g[f[x]] := y. It might not always be easy to find g^-1[y] and then define f[x] that way. I gave an example of g(x) as 1/x, in this case. Hope that's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `InverseFunction` for this so long as your LHS is of the form `g[f[x]]`:

```
g[y_] := 1/y;
f[x_] := InverseFunction[g] @ (1/R[x] - A[x]/B[x])
f[x]
```

If `InverseFunction[g]` can be computed symbolically, then it might be more efficient to use immediate assignment for `f` instead (i.e, `f[x_] =` ) so that the inverse does not have to be re-computed each time you call `f`, but you'll need to be careful that `x` is not already defined then. You can use `Block` or `Module` to ensure this, if necessary:

```
Block[{x},
 f[x_] = InverseFunction[g] @ (1/R[x] - A[x]/B[x])
]
```

If you don't like defining an axillary function `g`, you can use pure functions instead (e.g., `InverseFunction[1/# &]`).